# Ruby on Rails multiple classes with same name under different namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, namespaces

I have some classes under a Rails application `ApplicationName`. They are autoloaded as part of Rails on the boot of my application server. Some are `ActiveRecord` models, some are PORO models, and some are service classes, which are also PORO's. Some of these classes have the same name, but are under different namespaces such as `User` and `NameSpaced::User`, which represent different objects with similar concepts.

In one of the namespaced classes, I do some ETL work to get a foreign object to meld into an `ActiveRecord` model in my database. Since the `ActiveRecord` model by default is under the global `ApplicationName` namespace, I figured `ApplicationName::ModelName` would work, and I expected it to return the top level object (the `ActiveRecord` model). Instead, I got an unintialized constant error. `ApplicationName::Application::ModelName` returns it, but I get a warning about the class referencing the toplevel namespace (as I expected, considering that `ActiveRecord` object resides up there). The `ModelName` model conflicts with another model under a different namespace (for the sake of argument we'll call it `DifferentNameSpace`). Things look like:

```
module ApplicationName
  class Application < Rails::Application
   # do autoload stuff here
  end
end

class ModelName
end

module DifferentNameSpace
  class ModelName
  end
end
```

Is there any way to specifically call `ApplicationName::ModelName` or to do an `ApplicationName::Application::ModelName` without the warning? Right now it works if I do `::ModelName`, but that looks ugly.

Comment: Just add `ModelName = ::ModelName` inside `ApplicationName::Application`.

Comment: I think the `::ModelName` solution is the most explicit and correct one, kind of an absolute reference. I guess you will get used to it and the ugliness will transform into developer happines :) .